# SQLite: .Net much slower than native?

Tags: c#, performance, sqlite, system.data.sqlite, database-performance

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM [GeoName]
WHERE ((-26.3665122100029-Lat)*(-26.3665122100029-Lat))+((27.5978928658078-Long)*(27.5978928658078-Long)) < 0.005
ORDER BY ((-26.3665122100029-Lat)*(-26.3665122100029-Lat))+((27.5978928658078-Long)*(27.5978928658078-Long))
LIMIT 20
```

This returns the 20 closest points.

Running this in native sqlite returns a result within 78ms, but from within the .Net sqlite environment it takes nearly 1400ms.

Any suggestions?

I have this query within my ORM structure and using parameterized values. Have also tried it as a native text query.

The code that runs the query (inside my ORM layers):

```
private static IDataReader CallSqlReader(string SqlStatement, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    ConnectionCheck();

    try
    {
        var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = SqlStatement;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
        return cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch { }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a managed wrapper over the native sqlite3.dll or a fully managed implementation ?

Comment: Hi Guys. I'm using the ADO.Net DLL and not the native one. Posting the code as well...

Comment: You are still not giving us the whole picture. We also need to see the query passed in the `SqlStatement` parameter of `CallSqlReader()`. Don't worry, we are not going to steal your industrial secrets. Also we would like to see the exact definition of your table, (`CREATE TABLE`) and perhaps also to know how many rows are contained within that table.

Comment: Sorry don't see the point of posting allot of scaffolding code (don't mind sharing it anyway). The query is as per above, and the eventual code running it is posted as well. I can't post too much as i have signed confidentiality agreements with my client... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected that a non-native means of accessing a database will be slower, perhaps much slower, than the native means of accessing same database. But wait to see if someone shows up who has had this problem before and has been able to come up with some kind of solution to it.  In the mean time, it will probably help if you show exactly how you execute this query from within dotnet.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've assumed that ADO.Net interface will take it's pound of flesh, as well as my ORM code. The Performance analysis of the code clearly indicated that the query itself ran for 1.5 seconds compared to the 78ms in native... Just think i'm doing something wrong here?