# Microsoft replacement of SQL Server CE

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

Why is SQL Server CE deprecated and what is (or will be) Microsoft replacement for portable database? `LocalDB` requires local .msi installation, and SQlite requires 3rd-party bindings to ADO.NET. Working in Visual Studio, I would prefer Microsoft solution. Given the growing importance of portable database, I am intrigued why SQL Server CE was dropped with no committed replacement by Microsoft.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition/

Comment: @David Brabant, "2. Disk usage: all SQL Server Compact binaries amount to some 4MBs, while LocalDB installation takes 140MBs." ... Download size  of 32MB and size on disk 160MB?? How is that even consider "portable"?

Comment: Depending on your constraints / requirements, another option to consider might be Esent. I've used successfully several times. However, if you heavily rely on SQL for your queries, that won't do. https://managedesent.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you David. I have used SQLCE 4.0 am now using Sqlite (just because SQLCE is "deprecated".  I just feel uncomfortable learning new things to do the same work, and why there is no "new" SQLCE from Microsoft.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777456/sqlite-net-much-slower-than-native  I would also expect having any .NET wrapper will make it significantly slower